# Windows CListCtrl and groups

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to create simple group in CListrCtrl with one element, but it doesn't show me anything:

```
EnableGroupView(TRUE);

LVGROUP group = { 0 };
group.cbSize = sizeof(LVGROUP); 
group.iGroupId = 1;
group.state = LVGS_NORMAL; 
group.mask = LVGF_GROUPID | LVGF_HEADER | LVGF_STATE | LVGF_ALIGN;
group.uAlign = LVGA_HEADER_LEFT;

int idx = InsertGroup(0, &group);

LVITEM item = {0};
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;// | LVIF_GROUPID;
item.iItem = 0;
item.iSubItem = 0;
item.pszText = L"aa";
item.cchTextMax = 3;
item.state = 0;
item.stateMask = LVIS_SELECTED;
item.iGroupId = idx;
InsertItem(&item);
```

BTW, I can see this item only if I don't enable group view mode. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: Windows 7 + MSVC 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LVITEM::iGroupId` member expects a **group ID** but you are passing it a **group index** instead.  That is why you cannot see the item - you are adding it to a non-existent group.  You need to set `item.iGroupId` to `group.iGroupId` (ie `1`) instead.

Comment: thanks, that was my mistake. I'm very surprised about insufficiency of  samples for such control as CListCtrl...